Audio amplifier cutting off and clicking PAM8304
I have designed a PCB with a PAM8304 Mono Class D Audio Amplifier and MAX1708 5v step converter to drive a 4 ohm speaker. The device will be battery powered with 3.3v battery hence the step up converter to power the amplifier. Currently I can hear music at very low volumes however when I start to turn up the volume I hear lots of clicking and no music. Suspecting it was something to do with PCB layout I tested the PAM8304 on a breadboard copying the exact schematic from the datasheet. I had a 100K resistor and 0.1uf capacitor on each input with negative connected to ground. I also have a 1 uF capacitor going from VDD to ground and a 0.1uF capacitor from PVDD to ground. Powering the circuit with a 3.9V I was able to hear music and however there was still substantial clicking at certain parts of the song as I turned up the volume. I was able to reduce this clicking by connected another speaker driver in series, although the clicking is still there at certain notes in the song. My main problem now is that I cannot increase the voltage past 3.9V. Any increase in supply voltage past 3.9V results in clicking and then the amplifier turns off altogether.
I have tried adding many more capacitors, both ceramic and electrolytic, from VDD and PVDD to GND to no avail. I have also tried using another PAM8304 chip on the breadboard but no change.
Using the oscilloscope I noticed that the input signal was a regular looking audio waveform however the output of the amplifier was a square waveform. When music is paused the square waveform is clear and steady and when music is playing the square waveform remains but the signal oscillates with the music.
Thank you very much for you help.
datasheet https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/115/PAM8304-273747.pdf

Welcome! Please post a schematic.

Hi winny, i have attached  schematic I am recreating on my breadboard. The only differences are I have added a 0.1uF capacitor from PVDD to GND and 1uF electrolytic cap in addition to a ceramic 1uF cap from VDD to GND. I also have 2 speakers in series as this seemed to reduce the clicking. I am using an audio signal from a aux cable coming out of my laptop. thank you

Good. Now post oscillograms of Vdd, In and Out.

Ive attached the images of the oscilloscope. top is input, second is output, third is VDD

@CADman 40 nS/div might be a bit too fast to capture problems on the power rail. Try slowing it down in steps to perhaps 1 ms/div and see if anything shows up. Also, make sure to measure it near the pin of the IC, not at the PSU output.

That thing is switching at ~500kHz looking at the scope image. Rise and fall times have to be in the tens of ns or lower. Forget about breadboard, only a properly designed PCB with good power supply decoupling will do...

thank you both for your responses, i am now back to testing the amplifier on the PCB. @AndrewMorton I have tried slowing down to 1ms/div and measured VCC again. The voltage remains reasonable constant around 5V with noise ranging from 4.80v to around 5.30V with no noticeable large spikes. When the audio clicks there is a a drop in voltage to zero and then quickly returns to 5V. On the PCB i am only able to hear music at very low levels beyond which i can only hear clicking. I am quite new to electronics and not sure what kind of other things to look out for on the oscilloscope.

@Unimportant, I have ditched the breadboard and am now back to testing the PCB. I have a decoupling capacitor from VCC to GND as close as possible to the amplifier and have tried increasing the capacitor value from 1uF to 47uF but still can only hear music at very low volumes. I tested with 3.7V by adding a jumper wire from 3.7V straight to the amplifier VCC pin and it works thought is too quiet. I need it to run off the 5V from the boost converter to make it loud enough. Any idea why running the amplifier off voltages over 4V causes it to cut out?

@CADman Does the amplifier work correctly if you feed it directly from a bench PSU? (Taking any necessary precautions to prevent damage to the regulator you're bypassing.)

@AndrewMorton it working when using the power supply directly to the amplifier up to around 4.9/4.9V supply so its better. However, still doesn't work using the 5V coming from boost converter.

@CADman If you have been supplying the boost converter from a battery, then you should supply it from the bench PSU to test. If it works, then the battery cannot supply enough current. If it does not work, then the boost converter is inadequate - did you follow the design guidelines, including any heatsinking that it may require?

@AndrewMorton, i have been using the PSU for testing so far. The regulator seems to work and be adequate as i have measured the voltage at its output and also at the input to the amplifier and it is 5.1V.  The amplifier seems to not be able to run on 4.3V with regulator or past 4.9V with power supply directly powering the amplifier. The amplifier has a max supply voltage of 6.5V. I thought this would be noise exceeding the max supply voltage and shutting down the amplifier, however using the oscilloscope measuring the amplifier VCC it never exceeded more than around 5.3V.

@CADman If the amp works with the bench PSU and does not work with the regulator, which part do you deduce is most likely to be the problem? It might be that there are two problem areas: 1) the regulator cannot provide the power continuously because of either overheating shutdown or overcurrent shutdown, or 2) the amplifier is going into overheating shutdown. Or both.

@CADman If you put a small amout of 99% isopropanol on an IC and it boils then the temperature is over 80 °C. (You will get an annoying burn on your finger that takes a few days to heal if you test it with your finger at that temperature.) Can you [edit] your question to add a photo of the circuit board, please?
